# python3 subprocess.run() get The system cannot find the file specified in Windows docker container

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, docker-container, docker-for-windows

When running

`subprocess.run(args=['ls /'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`

in a window docker container, it occurs error which says:

> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

But it never happens on my windows host machine.

python version: 3.6.6
windows docker image: winservercore:1803

Any clues or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
args=['ls /']
```

You are trying to run a single command named `ls /`; in a Windows context where there are routinely file extensions, it might be named `ls /.exe`.  You probably mean that to be two separate words, which need to be included separately in the list of arguments

```
args=['ls', '/']
```

Do *not* specify `shell=True`.  It's a dangerous option that makes your script a potential vector for security issues.

Comment: Thanks you David, your advice does work. However, I just wonder why the method I provide can work on my **windows 10 host machine** with `totally` the same Python version.   Additionally, when I try to execute two commands in one line, like `args=['ls', '/', ';', 'echo', '1']`, it will occur error, which seems to parse `echo 1` as a parameter in `ls`